# Sum and subtraction to a single column

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here is my query:

```
select year(p.datetimeentered) as Year, month(p.datetimeentered), datename(month, p.datetimeentered) as Month, st.type as SubType, sum(p.totalpaid) as TotalPaid from master m
inner join jm_subpoena s on s.number = m.number
inner join payhistory p on p.number = m.number
inner join jm_subpoenatypes st on st.id = s.typeid
where p.batchtype in ('PU','PUR','PA','PAR')
and p.datetimeentered > s.completeDate
group by year(p.datetimeentered), month(p.datetimeentered), datename(month, p.datetimeentered), st.type, p.batchtype
order by year(p.datetimeentered), month(p.datetimeentered), datename(month, p.datetimeentered), st.type, p.batchtype
```

Here is the criteria for the `TotalPaid` column.

When `p.batchtype` is `PU` or `PA` I need to sum those totals
When `p.batchtype` is `PUR` or `PAR` I need to sum those totals
then I need to subtract the two numbers from each other.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the addition/subtraction as part of the summation:

```
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN p.batchtype IN ('PU','PA') THEN p.totalpaid 
    WHEN p.batchtype IN ('PUR','PAR') THEN -p.totalpaid 
    ELSE 0 
END) as TotalPaid
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a case statement:

```
Case when p.batch in ('PU','PA') then x + y
else when p.batch in ('PUR, PAR') then x-y
end as YourColumnNameHere
```

If my original interpretation was incorrect, then pobrelkey's suggestion is spot on:

```
sum (
when p.batch in ('PU','PA') then totalpaid
    else when p.batch in ('PUR, PAR') then -totalpaid)
end as YourColumnNameHere
```

Comment: Wrap this answer within the SUM function as suggested by @pobrelkey

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure.  The OP said `subtract the two numbers from each other`, so I was thinking that meant two columns on the same row.

Comment: I was thinking this: `SUM( Case when p.batch in ('PU','PA') then x + y else when p.batch in ('pur','par') then x - y end ) as YourColumnNameHere`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Y, M, DATENM, SUBTYPE, (PU_PA_TotalPaid - PUR_PAR_TotalPaid) AS PUMINUSPUR, (PUR_PAR_TotalPaid - PU_PA_TotalPaid) AS PURMINUSPU
FROM
(select year(p.datetimeentered) as Y, month(p.datetimeentered) AS M, datename(month, p.datetimeentered) as DATENM, st.type as SubType, p.batchtype,
SUM(CASE WHEN p.batchtype IN ('PU', 'PA') THEN (p.totalpaid) ELSE 0 END) as PU_PA_TotalPaid ,
SUM(CASE WHEN p.batchtype IN ('PUR', 'PAR') THEN (p.totalpaid) ELSE 0 END) as PUR_PAR_TotalPaid 
from master m
inner join jm_subpoena s on s.number = m.number
inner join payhistory p on p.number = m.number
inner join jm_subpoenatypes st on st.id = s.typeid
where p.batchtype in ('PU','PUR','PA','PAR')
and p.datetimeentered > s.completeDate
group by year(p.datetimeentered), month(p.datetimeentered), datename(month, p.datetimeentered), st.type, p.batchtype
order by year(p.datetimeentered), month(p.datetimeentered), datename(month, p.datetimeentered), st.type, p.batchtype
) A
ORDER BY Y, M, DATENM, SUBTYPE,batchtype
```